# iOS UITableView shows extra padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView in a UITabBarController. When the view is first shown the tableview shows extra padding on the topside. When I switch to a other tab and then back. It appears to be in the correct position.

So my question is how do I remove this annoying padding and make it stay away.

What I have tried (but maybe incorrect?):

- Uncheck option under bar etc..
- Make the table header and view size of 0.01f and tried it with nil and 0.

Probably thousand more things but I these these I came across the most on stack overflow

Screenshot of problem:

[image]

The problem is the blue area

Comment: have u set delta height and delta y for ios 7 ?

Comment: Not sure what that Is?

Comment: May be a screenshot of that can help us

Comment: It isn't a xib. It is made through storyboard

Comment: Is this a UIViewController with a table in it or UITableViewController?

Comment: UIViewcontroller with table

Answer (score 0):

To avoid extra padding, set your tableview's content insets to Zero.

```
self.tblView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.tblView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Comment: facing this issue with iOS7 or iOS6? And that blue part is the padding which you are referring?

Comment: Facing iOS 7 and yes the padding is the blue part. The blue part is the background color

Answer (score 0):

Did you offset this in iOS 7 to compensate for the transparent status bar? Regardless, try this piece of code:

```
 self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

This should also work but it's not exactly proper:

```
 tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-36, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```